# We have to retrain the model if there is small change in dataset or database?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am using database for training my model,I have to train my model on new images for that We have to retrain the model if there is small change in dataset or database ?

And is it necessary to retrain the model on new images is there any other way to train my model instead of retrain?(It should update the things without forgetting the previous weights)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Like most questions of this nature, the answer is: It really depends on the problem you are trying to solve and how you are trying to solve it.  You have told us nothing about either of those things.

Answer (score 0):

If the new images are of the same class on which the model has been trained, then you don't have to retrain. But if it is for a new class you will need to retrain your model.

And "*We have to retrain the model if there is small change in dataset or database?*" can you please elaborate little more regarding data set or database

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sure i will elaborate For Example if we are using person database we are adding new person or deleting the exiting person from the database  for that we have to retrain the model, there is any  other way instead of retraining the model so that it can identify the new person who is added.